# Changing a singly linked list to a doubly linked list

Tags: python, data-structures, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I created a singly linked list function and my professor said for extra credit we can change it into a doubly linked list. I read a few things such as adding a prev_node function such as this.

```
class ListNode(object):

    def __init__(self, item = None, prev = None, link = None):

        '''creates a ListNode with the specified data value and link
        post: creates a ListNode with the specified data value and link'''

        self.item = item
        self.prev = prev
        self.link = link
```

However, I am confused on where to go from there. I know I need to add a tail as well as a head like I did here.

```
from DoublyListNode import ListNode

class LinkedList(object):

    #--------------------------------------------------------------

    def __init__(self, seq=()):

        """ Pre: Creates a Linked List
        Post: Creates a list containing the items in the seq=()"""

        if seq == ():

            # If there is no items to be put into the list, then it creates an empty one.
            self.head = None
            self.tail = None

        else:

            # Creates a node for the first item.
            self.head = ListNode(seq[0], None)

            # If there are remaining items, then they're added while keeping track of the last node.
            last = self.head
            for item in seq[1:]:
                last.link = ListNode(item, None)
                last = last.link

        self.size = len(seq)
```

Could anyone tell me, ( NOT DO IT FOR ME), what I have to do in order to change my linkedlist into a doubly linkedlist? I know I have to reference now the tail as well as the head but I'm pretty stumped on how to do that.

Comment: Any time you append a new node to `tail`, replace `tail` with the new node. Any time you insert to position 0, replace `head` with the new node. Any time you remove `tail`, replace `tail` with the tail-node's `prev`. Any time you remove `head`, replace `head` withe the head-node's `next`.

Comment: Note that being singly linked or doubly-linked doesn't actually change anything about the linked-list behaves. It just changes how you can iterate; In a singly-linked-list you can only iterate from head->tail, in a doubly-linked-list you can iterate in either direction. Technically speaking in both cases it would be useful to store `tail`; it makes appending to the list much faster (though keeping `tail` up to date is harder in a singly-linked list since you can't find the new `tail` from the old one, you have to iterate the whole list).

Comment: Rosetta code has implementations of basic data structures in many languages. There is definitely a python doubly linked list. Looking for that may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python, but here's a way to do it in Haskell:

```hs
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Vector (Vector, (!), fromList)

data DLL a = DLL {prevP :: Maybe (DLL a),
                  val :: a,
                  nextP :: Maybe (DLL a)}

list2DLL :: [a]->DLL a
list2DLL = vec2DLL . fromList

prev :: Int -> Maybe Int
prev i | i <= 0 = Nothing
prev i = Just (i-1)

next :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
next i lim | i < lim-1 = Just(i+1)
next _ _ = Nothing

vec2DLL :: Vector a -> DLL a
vec2DLL v = scaffold ! 0 where
  scaffold = V.mapWithIndex go v
  go i a = DLL (fmap (scaffold!) $ prev i)
               a
               (fmap (scaffold!) $ next i (length v))
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know I have to reference now the tail as well as the head but I'm pretty stumped on how to do that.

A great way to get started is to write out in English what it is you want to do:

> I have a Linked List and I need to convert it to a doubly linked list. To do this, each node needs to keep track of a `prev` and `next`, and my list needs a `head` and `tail` node. When I create the list, `head` and `tail` should point at the same item. When I add a new item to my list, it should become the last node, its `.prev` element should be the previous `.tail`, and it should be the `.next` item for that item as well.

Once you have a description of what you want to do, then it should be relatively straightforward to translate that into code.